# Tabs only rendering first page

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms

I have an app I am making and I am using jquery tab control for navigation. Everything renders properly for the first page, but the second page is completely blank for the content. When I navigate from another tab to the first tab, the first tab still displays correctly.

Here is my master page with the tabs

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">

    <head id="Head1" runat="server">
        <title></title>
        <link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="Styles/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/footable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/footable.sort.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/footable.paginate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link href="Styles/footable.core.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="Styles/footable.standalone.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                $(".tabs").tabs();
            });

            $(".tabs").on('click', function() {
                __doPostBack('tabs', '');
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form id="Form1" runat="server">
            <div class="page">
                <div class="header">
                    <div class="title">
                         <h1>
                    &nbsp;<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/CCLogo.jpg" />
                </h1>

                    </div>
                    <div class="loginDisplay">
                        <asp:LoginView ID="HeadLoginView" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
                            <LoggedInTemplate>Welcome <span class="bold"><asp:LoginName ID="HeadLoginName" runat="server" /></span>! [
                                <asp:LoginStatus ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Log Out" LogoutPageUrl="~/" />]</LoggedInTemplate>
                        </asp:LoginView>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear hideSkiplink">
                        <div id="tabs" class="tabs">
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="My Audits.aspx">My Audits</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="My Claims.aspx">My Claims</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="Reports.aspx">Reports</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="Maintenance.aspx">Maintenance</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="main">
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server" />
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="footer"></div>
        </form>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Where is the tab content?  These just look like links to other pages.  If one of those other pages is blank, where do you define the content for that other page?

Comment: All the other content is in those pages the links are pointed to

Comment: Does the second page work if you navigate to it manually instead of clicking on the link?  I don't see how this issue relates to jQuery UI tabs or to the code posted.  Do you have a live example of the problem that we could see?

Comment: The page works fine if I manually navigate to it, it just isn't being rendered in the tab content area

Comment: I don't even see a tab content area in this code.  I see a `ContentPlaceHolder` which should render the page's content when it loads.  When you click on the jQuery UI tabs, what happens?  Does the browser make a full request to the linked page?  Or is that request being overridden by the tabs plugin?

Comment: The request is being overridden by the tabs plugin

Comment: Is it making the AJAX request?  What is the response from the server?  (Note: You can monitor requests and responses in your browser's debugging tools.)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I removed the function below and it is working properly.

```
  $(".tabs").on('click', function() {
            __doPostBack('tabs', '');
        });
```